# Search for invitations where I have not responded

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, gmail-search

Is there any way in Gmail to search for invitations (calendar invites) I have received where I have not responded / RSVP'd?

Comment: Using calendar.google.com any events you haven't responded to yet will have a left facing arrow on the event assuming you have Calendar set to "Automatically add invitations to my calendar".

Comment: @Folk That's a good alternative which achieves a similar result. If you submit this as an answer I shall accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using calendar.google.com any events you haven't responded to yet will have a left facing arrow on the event assuming you have Calendar set to "Automatically add invitations to my calendar".

Answer (score 0):

Not with Gmail search. I don't see anything in a message for a calendar invitation that's been responded to that's different one from that hasn't.

The RSVP "Quick Action" in the subject line will show your response, but only when you click on it, and that's separate from the mail message and things you could search for.

This certainly seems like it would be useful. Let's hope Google adds something to find pending invitations soon.

Comment: still waiting...